# Can't interact with window during a Method is working C#

Tags: c#

If I start a Method which needs 5s until it is finished. It works perfectly. BUT, During this Time I can't interact with the Window.

For example:
You want a user of this program to start a Method which opens with Selenium a Webside and search 100 websites which include the name "Code".. and this needs 100s. But during this time you can't interact with the user-Interface, you can't close it.

Window:

[image]

For Example :

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
().Window.Maximize();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Thank you

Comment: You are running the code on the main thread. Run it on a different thread or if you can make it async.

Comment: You should be looking at finishing the time-consuming task using non-blocking  ( UI thread) way. Eg: asynchronous

Comment: Do you know how I can run the code on a different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You application runs currently in a single thread. That means it can work on  one thing at the same time. In this case, handle interactions with your Window or execute your long running code.

One possible option, would be to execute your long running code on a separate thread. More info in [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-threads-in-c-sharp/).

C# has a perfect solution for executing work in background - Tasks. I recommend you using Tasks instead of Threads for small tasks. Tasks class lets you create tasks and run them asynchronously. A task is an object that represents some work that should be done. The task can tell you if the work is completed and if the operation returns a result, the task gives you the result.

To create a task and run it, you simply pass your Action as argument to StartNew method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
});
```

Other ways of starting a Task [here](https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/).

You can read more about Tasks in [this msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)